# How do I add this (recaptcha) form dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, captcha

I have a .aspx file and I want to dynamically add the form and controls below in my `<script>` tag. (Page-Language=C#)

```
<form runat="server">
        <asp:Label Visible=true ID="lblResult" runat="server" />

        <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
            ID="recaptcha"
            runat="server"
            Theme="red"
            PublicKey="6Ld4PcQSAAAAADvExkhlgujfXixYYeJ0x6zQDZan"
            PrivateKey="6Ld4PcQSAAAAABAg0i2Nk6FMjbstXQqCS2XRDoea"
        />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to add it dynamically? Although, its not exactly the answer to your question but more simpler way is to put the said markup in the placeholder control and sets placeholder's visibility as per your requirements.

And if you must add controls dynamically, you will still need a placeholder (after script tag) as parent and then you can create the need control hierarchy from code-behind. For example,

```
var form = new HtmlForm();

var label = new Label();
label.ID = "lblResult";
form.Controls.Add(label);

var captcha = new RecaptchaControl();
captcha.ID = "recaptcha";
...

placeholder.Controls.Add(form);
```

Comment: If I were to change the visibility dynamically, will it still be seen in the source?

Comment: @Adam, if you set visibility for any server control as false then there is no markup is generated for it (or its children). So it will not visible from view-source.